# db schema for storing survey matrix questions and answers

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, database-schema, survey, db-schema

I'm trying to create a db schema to store survey questions and answers whereas I'm not able to think of the schema to hold the data.

Here's my sample question that I want to store in database:

[image]

Any pointers on how do I do that is highly appreciated!

PS: I've gone through these posts on SO but they didn't help:

[Relational Database System with dynamic columns with dynamic rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411316/relational-database-system-with-dynamic-columns-with-dynamic-rows)

[Storing a distance matrix in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363119/storing-a-distance-matrix-in-db)

[SQL design for survey with answers of different data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764469/sql-design-for-survey-with-answers-of-different-data-types?rq=1)

**Edit 1**

PS:

I want to create a schema to store the all the question types from SurveyMonkey.com and Qualtrics.com. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Google stackoverflow questions about sql and questionaires/surveys. Read about EAV and its problems. (Eg search my answers for EAV).

One choice is to use a base table per question with a column for vertical and a column for horizontal, where queries about multiple questions query the database metadata & with the DBMS managing question integrity. The other choice is EAV where every query about a question involves building the corresponding table from the previous sentence and integrity is managed by you via complex constraints.

The only disadvantage to the first option is that current DBMSes don't make DDL updates as efficient as DML updates. You should structure your software to be independent of the option you are currently choosing. To the extent that you use EAV you are programming your own DBMS.

You can find example survey data export and download formats for answers and surveys, eg [SurveyMonkey.com](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/XLS-Exports) and Qualtrics.com ([data](http://www.qualtrics.com/blog/customer-satisfaction-survey-questions/) or [surveys](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/advanced-building/advanced-options-drop-down/import-and-export-surveys/)).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL version

`CREATE TABLE MatrixQuestion (
username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex Michael',
meal VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex breakfast, lunch, dinner',
rate TINYINT NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex 1:poor 2:average 3:fair 4:good 5:awesome',
PRIMARY KEY (meal, username, rate)
);`

Comment: thanks for your reply but thumbs down to the answer!

Comment: @Sunny Explain what is wrong with this, by editing requirements into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create three table as

Table `FoodType`

```
FoodId - PK (TINYINT) -- 1,2,3
FoodName - varchar(50)-- breakfast, lunch, dinner
```

Table `RatingType`

```
RatingId - PK (TINYINT) --1,2,3,4,5
RatingName - varchar(50) --poor,average,fair,good, awesome
```

Table `UserRating`

```
UserName - varchar(100)
RatingId - FK (TINYINT)
FoodId - FK (TINYINT)
```

Now for every user Feedback make an entry in table `UserRating`

Comment: thanks for your reply... but how would you get all the rating names for a FoodId? also... it's not a single question always!

Comment: Try something like this `SELECT UR.UserName, RT.RatingName ,FT.FoodName
FROM UserRating UR
JOIN RatingType RT ON RT.RatingId = UR.RatingId
JOIN FoodType FT ON FT.FoodId = UR.FoodId
WHERE UR.FoodId = 1`

Comment: @Sunny & vijayp: This is the essentially same as the answer with MatrixQuestion(username,meal,rate) but with ids poinlessly added. Each design should have appropriate type checks.

Comment: @Sunny: We can't read your mind. Explain what "get all the rating names for a FoodId" and "it's not a single question always" mean.

Comment: @philipxy thanks for your valuable inputs. by saying "get all the rating names for a FoodId" I meant, vijayp didn't mention any Foreign Key to the FoodType Table so how would you get all the ratings.

I have edited my question for "it's not a single question always", PS. Thanks again for pointing me to EAV... gonna go look into this. thanks!